# Retrieve my Youtube videos with PHP

Tags: php

All,
do I really have to download the whole Zend framework to be able to get my youtube videos? I only want to display the ones that I uploaded and display them on my webpage. Do I have to make an authenticated call to do this or is there a simple way to just get my videos? I just want to display them on my page and then have the user have the ability to play them from there. None of my videos are private as well. Any suggestions on this are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTML (not PHP) you can embed videos in your webpages. See http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, all you have to do is get the code from youtube. If you go to share, you should see multiple options. You want 'embedded', then copy that to your web page.